# Retrieving a given pricelist from a PageObject in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, parameterized, pageobjects

I am learning Java to support my Webdriver skills and need to know the best practice for calling different pricelists against which to assert, using the PageObject model. I have an AUT for which the pricelist will change bi-annually. So, I don't want to have hardcoded values as I do presently:

```
 String summaryPaymentPrice = orderSummaryPage.yourOrderSummaryPaymentPrice();
    assertThat(summaryPaymentPrice, is("£15.00"));
```

What I want is a parameterized assertion, similar to:

```
 String summaryPaymentPrice = orderSummaryPage.yourOrderSummaryPaymentPrice();
    assertThat(summaryPaymentPrice, is(seniorMembership2014));
```

...where 'seniorMembership' is a variable held in a Pricelist page object, for a given Pricelist e.g. for 2014/2015 pricelist:

```
String seniorMembership2014 = "15.00"
```

My question is, how best to implement 2 or 3 pricelists in the page object page - I don't yet have the syntax knowledge for Java 7 - would an ArrayList of Strings be best? Can someone provide an example and demomstrate how the test class would call it?

EDIT: So, Vinayak has kindly suggested a HashMap. I have not used before, but something similar to the following in my PageObject might work:

```
    public void currentPriceList(){

    Map<String,String> priceList = new HashMap <String,String>();

    //2014/2015 Pricelist
    priceList.put("Child", new String ("10.00"));
    priceList.put("Senior", new String ("15.00"));
    priceList.put("Adult", new String ("20.00"));
```

I'm still not 100% clear how I would access each price in a  parameterized test

Comment: I will suggest you to use `HashMap<String,String>` where you will save `<key,value>` pair so `Key` will be 2014/2015 and `Value` - their respective string elements.

Comment: `priceList.get(string keyname)` in your example it will be `priceList.get("child");`